# Does bootstrap has method that shows the hidden class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently loading the data into the bootstrap table.the table class in my JSP is currently hidden. However, after loading the data into bootstrap table I am using :

```
$(function() {
var table = $('#Table').bootstrapTable({
    data: foo,
    pagination: true,
    pageList: [10, 25, 50, 100]
});
table.removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Is there anyway I can use bootstrap function instead of

```
table.removeClass('hidden');
```

to show the hidden class after the data loads?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `collapse` class instead of the `hidden` class, this way jQuery's `.show()` method can be used, for example:

```
table.show();
```

Comment: Is there any method that bootstrap provides that I can implement inside the function to make the table visible?something may be like visibility: true?